# What is the main task of ||= and helper method in RoR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**For example, i have a valid server on ruby on rails. My controller has this segment of code. Can you explain me more about ||=  and helper_method. What are they doing?**

```
  def current_user
        @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
      end
      helper_method :current_user
```

Comment: That's plain Ruby https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=what%27s+%7C%7C%3D+in+Ruby.

Comment: Oh, Thank you, i couldn't find this on google) Can you tell me a little bit about helper_method?

Comment: I hope you can always find an explanation for all basic ruby methods in ApiDock 
helper_method: https://apidock.com/rails/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method

Answer (score 1):

```rb
x ||= y
```

is shorthand for

```rb
x = x || y
```

Which means that x becomes y unless x is truthy.

In your context that means, that the `@current_user` will be assigned the `User.find...` unless it has already been assigned. It's a form of memoization.

Answer (score 0):

`x ||= y`, if you simplify this line of code, it'll be like the lines below

`if x.nil?
   x = y
 else
   x = x`

Comment: What about if x is false?

Answer (score 0):

`x ||= y` is the same as `x = x || x = y`, which means if x is not nil it will keep value x same or else it will reassign y to x.

Example 1.

```
x = nil
y = 2
x ||= y # this assigns x to 2
puts(x) # $> 2
```

Example 2.

```
x = 5
y = 2
x ||= y # this assigns x to 5
puts(x) # $> 5
```

Helper methods in rails are methods which are declared using helper_method :method_name

This is used in the view to render value instead [Read the documenation here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Helpers/ClassMethods/helper_method)